# Searchbar Text color on viewDidLoad

Tags: swift, uisearchbar, xcode13

Does anyone know why setting the text color of the search bar programmatically in **viewDidLoad** does not work and is requiring setting it to **.white** in **viewWillAppear**?

```
var searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    
searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false

searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search here"
searchController.searchBar.searchTextField.textColor = .white

self.navigationItem.searchController = searchController
```

Comment: yes we did it because due to searchController initialization delay so

Comment: Interesting.  I guess this is by design?

Comment: not by design because viewWillAppear call after a viewDidLoad  and viewDidAppear call after viewWillAppear so some of ui updates should not be executed in viewDidLoad due to its early execution. that's why

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, this has to be done in ViewWillAppear